# Functional analysis exercise: $\left(\int_{\Omega}|h|\rho dx\right)^{p}\leq \int_{\Omega}|h|^{p}\rho dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I have a doubt about this exercise:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be an open set, let $h \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\rho \colon \Omega \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$ be Lebesgue measurable functions and suppose that $\int_{\Omega}\rho dx =1$. Prove that for each $p \in [1,+\infty)$

\begin{equation}
\left(\int_{\Omega}|h|\rho dx\right)^{p}\leq \int_{\Omega}|h|^{p}\rho dx.
\end{equation}

My idea is to notice that if $d\nu=\rho dx$ i have that $\nu(\Omega)=1$ hence $\nu$ is a probability measure. Now i can use the Jensen inequality, that is $\left(\mathbb{E}[|h|]\right)^{p}\leq \mathbb{E}[|h|^{p}]$, and consequently follows

\begin{equation}
\left(\int_{\Omega}|h|d\nu\right)^{p}\leq \int_{\Omega}|h|^{p}d\nu,
\end{equation}

and recalling $d\nu=\rho dx$ i have the desired conclusion.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thankyou so much!